# how to ignore "?" directory in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

.gitignore uses [globbing](https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob), where `?` is a special character matching everything but "/". But what if I want to match exactly the `?` directory in order to ignore it?

Comment: Use `\?` for `?` itself.

Comment: That being said, this is a directory name of nightmares. I truly hope this is a theoretical question (which is fine).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\` to escape `.gitignore` pattern characters. [[source](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)]

So in your case `\?` should do the work.